# SitesManager.addSite method in Piwik API isn't giving me a response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, matomo

I'm trying to return the siteID of the site I've created using the Piwik API.

I read that the siteID is returned, though i'm not seeing anything.

The API call is correct as I'm seeing the site show up in the Piwik dashboard.

```
def newSite(site = Site.new)
    options = {:query => {:method => 'SitesManager.addSite', :siteName => URI::encode(site.name), :urls => site.url}}
    options.deep_merge!(@auth)
    return self.class.get("/index.php", options)

end
```

What call do I need to add a new site and return the ID of the new site?

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested it (using Piwik 2.9.1) and it's working fine.

Returned value (I used format=json):

`{"value":<idsite>}`